# Alternate section title for use in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I'm TeXing a course for a teacher of mine, and he wants me to have the section titles in the headers (I use `fancyhdr` to achieve this). He also wants me to retain the section titles he gave me in the original (word) file.

Since some of these section titles are too long to fit in the header title, is there a way to define a shorter version that is to be used in the header?

Enabling multiple header lines would also do.

I'm using the `book` class.

Comment: what document class are you using?

Comment: @Ian ~ I'm using the book class. Put it in my question too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the optional argument of `\section` in addition:

```
\section[short title]{long title}
```

This works for `\chapter` and other headings as well.

Note, that short title would be used in the table of contents as well. This is meaningful, in my opinion.

Comment: about 30 seconds quicker than me!

Comment: @Ian: just luck :) I'm sitting in the train and UMTS comes and goes frequently. Thanks for supporting. :-)

Comment: wow... had no idea this existed!!